# Generating a random number between x and y where the odds gravitate towards the average of a and b?

Tags: probability

I'm designing a computer game that will include genetics. Characters have a set of stats that can range between 0 and 12. These stats can be inherited, but just because both parents have a low score in something doesn't guarantee that the resulting offspring will have a low score. Even if they both have 0, there should still be a slim chance of any offspring rolling a 12.

What I need is a random number generator, where the possible range of results is always 0 to 12 but the odds are tilted based on the corresponding stats of the parents. I think the parents' stats should be averaged, thus one having a high score and the other having a low score will result in offspring being disproportionately likely to roll in the middle of the range.

This is for a program, so I'm not limited to real-world dice. I could make a die roll between any two arbitrary numbers if I needed. I thought about a roll-and-keep system, but I can't figure out the math for that without just manually working out every possibility so testing isn't easy.

Comment: Are values to be whole numbers or real numbers?

Comment: All values have to be an integer, aka whole numbers.

Comment: You can write out whatever distribution you like.. simple piecewise linear (two lines intersecting at the mean) should get the job done...you vary the slopes as you like.  That's a simple method, but you can vary it if you have more requirements.

Comment: The important thing is to get the shape you want.  You can then work out the relevant probability distribution and scale the whole picture to make the total $1$.

Comment: That does give me an idea. Find the average, then roll two numbers between 0 and 12. The closest to the average is the one that's chosen. This should in theory create a bias towards the average, while never making 0 and 12 impossible. I could increase the number of numbers rolled to increase the bias. From my understanding, in roll and keep systems any dicepools 3 and beyond practically make one result guaranteed. This is why I think 2 rolls would be best.

Comment: Alternative approach is to divide the region [0-12] into $n$ sectors, and assign a probability of a specific sector occurring based on the reciprocal of how far away the sector's midpoint is from the average.  For example, with 6 the average, the [5-6] sector would be assigned a relative probability of 1/(0.5), while the [0-1] sector would be assigned a relative probability of 1/(5.5).  So, the [5-6] sector is 11 times more likely to occur than the [0-1] sector.  Then, you have to fine tune the relative likelihoods of each sector, based on *what makes sense* to you.

Comment: The result is not that different than rolling two dice, where the probability of their sum being 7 is 6 times more likely than the probability of their sum being 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
from math import exp, sqrt, pi

def generate_offspring_stat(parent1_stat, parent2_stat):
    avg = (parent1_stat + parent2_stat) / 2
    variance = 2.0  # Adjust this value to control the spread of the distribution
    
    probabilities = []
    cumulative_prob = 0.0
    
    for value in range(13):
        probability = (1 / sqrt(2 * pi * variance)) * exp(-(value - avg)**2 / (2 * variance))
        probabilities.append(probability)
        cumulative_prob += probability
    
    # Normalize probabilities
    probabilities = [p / cumulative_prob for p in probabilities]
    
    random_num = random.random()
    cumulative_prob = 0.0
    
    for value, probability in enumerate(probabilities):
        cumulative_prob += probability
        if random_num <= cumulative_prob:
            return value
    
    return 12  # Default to 12 if the loop finishes without returning a value

# Example usage
parent1_stat = 5
parent2_stat = 2

offspring_stat = generate_offspring_stat(parent1_stat, parent2_stat)
print(offspring_stat)
```

Edit: I wrote it in Python, then just convert it to whatever language you like. I have not tested the code yet, but this is the best I got.